# android SQLite- write default values to database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a database as follows. I want to write default values to this table when the table is created

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
    KEY_CTYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
    KEY_SNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
    KEY_SNUMB + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
    KEY_USRN  + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
    KEY_PASS  + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
    KEY_EMPTY + " INTEGER);"
);
```

how should i do it?

Comment: No research, dude... http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Answer (score 1):

in the `oncreate` after creating the Table add all the entries using a `for loop`

After

```
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + KEY_CTYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            +  KEY_SNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            +  KEY_SNUMB + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            +  KEY_USRN + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            +  KEY_PASS + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            +  KEY_EMPTY + " INTEGER);"
    );
```

call your `createEntry` method in a loop 8 times and add the default values using `ContentValues`